# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.SizeF'

Tags: c#

While trying to convert the `string` "A3" value to `System.Drawing.SizeF` faced with this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.SizeF'

An example of what I have tried is:

```
SizeF f = new SizeF();
f = "A3";
```

In my scenario, I'll pass this string value through one variable called `pdfSize`. The size can be anything like A3, A4 etc. How can i identify that dimensions for A4, A0 as mentioned for A3 is 297 mm * 420 mm.

**Question:** How to convert the `string` value like "A3" or "A4" into the `System.Drawing.SizeF` value?

Comment: What is your expected output? *"My rectangle has a height/width of A3."* would get you confused looks in real-life, so it's no surprise that the compiler reacts similarly.

Comment: `SizeF` is an ordered pair of floating-point numbers. What do "A3", "A4", etc, represent?

Comment: @ChrisFannin they're standard page sizes.  That have standard measurements.  That OP can find.  And that OP can use to construct an instance of SizeF.  If OP took a minute to think about it rather than ask us to do it for him :|

Comment: @Will: Ah, thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: I need to assign the string value to the sizeF variable. For example, refer the below code.                                                                                              SizeF f = new SizeF();
            f = "A3";

Comment: @Will I realized that as soon as I asked it.

Comment: @velmurugan You can't assign a string. You should store the values directly. Here is the sizing information [a3 a4 a5 paper size - Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=a3%20a4%20a5%20paper%20size)

Comment: You need to identify that A3 is 297 mm × 420 mm and use those numbers to construct your SizeF.

Comment: @Will: Thanks. But in my scenario i'll pass this string value through one variable called pdfSize. The size can be anything like A3, A4 etc. How can i identify that dimensions for A4, A0 as mentioned for A3 is 297 mm * 420 mm.

Comment: @velmurugan You need to store all of the sizes you want. The link I gave gives a quick reference. I also posted an answer with an example of how to store and retrieve them.

Comment: @velmurugan Did my answer example help at all? It can be adjusted if it doesn't quite fit what you're looking for.

Comment: @ChrisFannin Thanks for the sample, it helped me to understand your answer.

Comment: @velmurugan I'm glad it helped. Upvoting and/or marking as Accepted would be appreciated. It helps when I audit my open answers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly convert it. You need to do something like that:

```
float a4Height = 10;
float a4Width = 5;

float a3Height = 5;
float a3Width = 2;

private SizeF CreateSizeF(string pageSize)
{
    SizeF sizeF = null;

    if(pageSize == "A4")
    {
        sizeF = new System.Drawing.SizeF(a4Width, a4Height);
    }
    else if(pageSize == "A3")
    {
        sizeF = new System.Drawing.SizeF(a3Width, a3Height);
    }

    return sizeF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty example of how to store and use the values:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private Dictionary<string,SizeF> paperSizes = new Dictionary<string,SizeF>();

  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     paperSizes.Add("A2", new SizeF(420, 594));
     paperSizes.Add("A3", new SizeF(297, 420));
     paperSizes.Add("A4", new SizeF(210, 297));
     paperSizes.Add("A5", new SizeF(148, 210));

     comboBox1.Items.AddRange(paperSizes.Keys.ToList<string>().ToArray());
  }

  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (comboBox1.Text.Length > 0)
     {
        if (paperSizes.ContainsKey(comboBox1.Text))
        {
           MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} = {1} x {2}", comboBox1.Text, paperSizes[comboBox1.Text].Width, paperSizes[comboBox1.Text].Height));
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: A comprehensive list of paper sizes, including the A* values, as well as many many others, is available at the following link. Just add any entries that you want to utilize. -- [**Paper Sizes Chart**](http://resources.printhandbook.com/pages/paper-size-chart.php)